# how to remove an entire line in with a pattern using sed

Tags: sed

i have a file :

```
hi:: hello hai
welcome
bye
```

I want to remove the lines with the word `hi`

I tried the following command:

```
sed -i -e "/hi/d" filename
```

but the output was

```
 :: heloo hai
```

How can I remove the entire line using sed?? That is the line `"hi::hello hai"`

Comment: Strange, your command seems just fine.

Comment: Does it have to be sed ? Looks like typical grep -v.work

Comment: There's something wrong with your text file or your environment.  That command works just fine on that content for me here.

Comment: @damienfrancois probably wants sed for the in-place functionality, to avoid manually grepping into a new file and copying, or whatever.

Comment: Is MS windows involved? You probably have line-endings like \r\n. Use `dos2unix file` to clean that up, then retry. Your code should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^.*hi.*$/d`  can.t test right now so it is a wild guess

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient:

```
sed -e '/hi/d' file
```

Tested and works.

```
tom@eee ~ % cat test 
hi:: hello hai
welcome
bye
tom@eee ~ % sed -e '/hi/d' test
welcome
bye
```

Also as damienfrancois stated grep works too:

```
tom@eee ~ % grep -v 'hi' test 
welcome
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do this

```
awk '!/^hi/' file
welcome
bye
```

This will remove lines with `hi` in start of line.  You does not say if the world can be in middle of the sentence. If so, do:

```
awk '!/hi/'
welcome
bye
```